# How to change a setting on Samsung Device programmatically?

Tags: java, android, touch, screen, samsung

I'm writing an android java app that tracked screen touches to count pushups.
I would like to ensure touch sensitivity is at highest level. I noticed that in Samsung devices, there is an option in 'Settings' called 'Touch sensitivity' which can be toggled on and off. Also another setting called 'Accidental touch protection' which can be toggled on and off.

I'd like to toggle the 'Touch sensitivity' option on and the 'Accidental touch protection' option off. I'd like to do this programmatically in java or at least direct the user to the setting page so that he can turns the options on/off as needed.

Any idea how to achieve this using java code?

Many thanks indeed.

Comment: How are you planning to use screen touches to count pushups?  Put it beneath them and count on a bare chest touching the device?  Because there's a lot of problems with that idea, it doesn't really follow how touch screens work-  you're going to get a lot of phantom touches, bouncing, touch points forming, moving, and merging, etc.  Having written some complex multitouch algorithms in the past I can tell you that touch sensitivity for anything other than a single finger can get really wonky.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes, putting the device underneath and then count touches. I understand the complexities and I'm able to handle them but it would be difficult with the option 'touch sensitivity' turned off and 'Accidental touch protection' turned on for Samsung devices. Other devices work okay. Once these options fixed the app would work much better. Thanks

Comment: I would make sure to test with a large variety of people of different shapes (overweight, skinny, muscular, etc), curvature (big boobs, little boobs, no boobs, man boobs) and ethnicities.  I was writing a typing algorithm once that was reliant on multitouch.  We found that differences in individuals skin resistivity would make single touches get missed, or multiple get merged, or cause them to phantom disappear that got worse as the touch area increased.  The hardware and algorithms are not built for this.  Honestly you'd be better off with a physical button connected via bluetooth.

Comment: I mention ethnicities and genders because these problems were worse for women and asians, due to having small fingers and a tendency to lightly touch the device, where as white males (the original algorithm testers) were less delicate.  I would expect similar problems for something like this, the hardware isn't optimized for this use.